# is it possible to add feature  like primarykey in Core data?

Tags: iphone, core-data

Can I get results using  all type of queries through features of Core data? (like Primary key, forieghn key,alter,update )?
  or FMDB is better than using Coredata for running all type of SQL queries?

Core data will be useful in all situations?

Answer (score 2):

> Can I get results using all type of queries through features of Core data? (like Primary key, forieghn key,alter,update )? or FMDB is better than using Coredata for running all type of SQL queries?

Please take a look at the [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html)
There is no SQL in CoreData, Core Data is not a Database. The [Technology Overview](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdTechnologyOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009296-SW1) gives a good introduction about what core data is and what it is not.

> Core data will be useful in all situations?

No.